# How to add Reduce Learning Rate On Plateau in XGBoost?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

You know in TensorFlow, we use a callback named `ReduceLROnPlateau` which reduce our learning rate slightly when our model stops learning. Does anyone know how to do this in `XGBoost`? I want to know if there is any way to reduce learning when `XGBoost` model stops learning.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/betaboosting-2cd6c697eb93) claims:

> A quick Google search reveals that there has been some work done utilizing a decaying learning rate, one that starts out large and shrinks at each round. But we typically see no accuracy gains in Cross Validation and when looking at test error graphs there are minimal differences between its performance and using a regular old constant.

They wrote a Python package called [BetaBoost](https://pypi.org/project/BetaBoost/) to find an optimal sequence for the learning rate scheduler.

In principle they seem to use a function which returns learning rates for the `LearningRateScheduler`

```
from scipy.stats import beta
def beta_pdf(scalar=1.5,
             a=26,
             b=1,
             scale=80,
             loc=-68,
             floor=0.01,
             n_boosting_rounds=100):
    """
    Get the learning rate from the beta PDF
    Returns
    -------
    lrs : list
        the resulting learning rates to use.
    """
    lrs = [scalar*beta.pdf(i,
                           a=a, 
                           b=b, 
                           scale=scale, 
                           loc=loc) 
           + floor for i in range(n_boosting_rounds)]
    return lrs

[...]

xgb.train(
[...],
callbacks=[xgb.callback.LearningRateScheduler(beta_pdf())]
)
```